# Neo4j: How to bring database back online

Tags: neo4j

I was running a large delete query and got an out of memory error, so the DB shutdown automatically.  I restarted it, but it is still showing as 'offline' in Neo4j desktop.

Here are the log entries from the restart:

```
2021-08-01 23:47:03.506+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-08-01 23:47:06.804+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.2.1 ========
Exception in thread "neo4j.Scheduler-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2021-08-01 23:47:22.505+0000 INFO  Sending metrics to CSV file at /Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-########-####-####-####-##########/metrics
2021-08-01 23:47:22.524+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2021-08-01 23:47:23.836+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-08-01 23:47:23.837+0000 INFO  Started.
```

Similarly, when I attempt to connect from a browser it tells me that the Neo4j database is unavailable.

In the log I can see that there is a Java out of memory error.  Why would this appear?  Does Neo4j queue/cache incomplete queries?  And how do I go about clearing it if I can't access the server?

The data is only test data, so I don't need to save it.  I do need to understand if I can fix it, and how, since I am putting the product through its paces for a new project.